# Tapestry internal redirection to static page

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, redirect, tapestry

I just want a Tapestry page to redirect to a static page like this :

http://www.myWebSite.com/home/myPage.tml
-> http://www.myWebSite.com/static/myStaticPage.html

I try to do this by returning a new URL, but i need to know the web site address for that (http://www.myWebSite.com/). So, i would like to know how to do this without knowing the web site address ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found : using the RequestGlobals service

```
String baseUrl = requestGlobals.getHTTPServletRequest().getRequestURL().toString().replaceFirst(requestGlobals.getHTTPServletRequest().getRequestURI(), "");
```

Just use it to build your URL string put it in a URL instance.

Answer (score 2):

You can inject (using @Inject) the HttpServletRequest directly in your page directly, without using RequestGlobals, and use its `getServerName()` method to get the server name. Not tested:

```
@Inject
private HttpServletRequest request;

Object onActivate() {
    return new java.net.URL("http://" + request.getServerName() " + "/myStaticPage.html");
}
```